# How to secure Jersey REST ressources

Tags: security, rest, angularjs, jersey

I am currently developing a web application using Java Jersey on the server side which provides RESTful resources and a AngularJS client application which makes REST calls to the Jersey application.

Now everything is working fine. Basically I have two servlets, one which needs authentication (Tomat Basic Auth) and one which is public. The one that is public is used to serve content for the public website (there are only GET calls). So my question is, if I need to secure these get calls? Is there any way I can make sure, that the REST ressource can only be called from the same context/port?

Because the server application and the client application are both deployed upon the same context (e.g. http://xyz.com/app for client and http://xyz.com/app-api for the rest ressource). Is this possible? Or is that not necessary?

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Greets
Marc

Comment: if you want you can disable CORS on your web server

Comment: How can I disable that? Is this a tomcat setting?

Comment: sorry I am not java guy but I am sure this has to be web server setting or java setting

Comment: does anybody else knows if its possible to disable CORS on tomcat? So that no REST calls (even with CURL) from outside the webserver are possible?

Comment: You cant set your resources to return a JSONP. It's something like CORS free. CORS are enable by default on your browser.